# R stat_compare_means - 3 decimals and p < 0.001 and "p" in italics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add *p* values to a ggplot. They should have three 3 decimals and if *p* < 0.001 then it should display that ("*p* < 0.001"). And the "*p*" should be in italics. Somehow one has to do it with sprintf but how exactly?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len")+
stat_compare_means(label = "p.format")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create the label via `?plotmath` notation to italicize the `p`, set argument `parse=TRUE` (which via `...` is passed to `geom_text`) and use `scales::label_pvalue` to format the p-value:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(
    label = paste0(
      "italic(p)",
      scales::label_pvalue()(..p..)
    )
  ),
  parse = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo, very helpful